# Status bar detects taps only when the UIWebView is scrolled down a bit

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate, uistatusbar

I have a `UIWebView` as the root view of a `UINavigationController`. When a webpage finishes to load, I hide the navigation bar, and I'm looking for a way to show it back. Right now, I'm trying to do that when the user taps the status bar ([this approach](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/) looks to me more complicated than what I want).

In order to accomplish this, firstly I get the scrollView of the webView:

```
for (id subview in mainWebView.subviews) {
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]) {
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).delegate = self;
    }
}
```

and then I use the delegate method:

```
-(BOOL) scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    return NO;
}
```

I was hoping that this would work, but here is what happens:

- Page loads, and navigation bar gets hidden (that's good)
- I try to tap the status bar, but nothing happens (that's bad)
- I scroll down so that the webview is "far" from the status bar
- Without letting the webview go, I tap the status bar with another finger and it works! (that's weird :)

Soooo, any help regarding that? Why is this happening?

Comment: @fabian789 I finally did it using the first link http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this again in iOS 5.0 and it seems to work as expected:

```
[self.webView.scrollView setDelegate:self];
[self.webView.scrollView setScrollsToTop:YES];
```

and then:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I solved it by :

```
[[[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setScrollsToTop:NO];
```

Also you can get access scrollView property in iOS 5 by :

```
webView.scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO ;
```

Comment: But how can you set the `scrollsToTop` to `NO`, and still get callbacks to `-scrollViewShouldScrollToTop`? Is this how it should work?