# Phonegap crashes when status bar tapped on iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios5, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Phonegap Xcode iOS app crashes when status bar is tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700310/phonegap-xcode-ios-app-crashes-when-status-bar-is-tapped)

I have an application using Phonegap 1.4.1 where I set the status bar as visible on iOS. When I tap and drag it pulls the notification tab just fine, but if I just tap on the bar/clock, I get an error on the phone. On the iOS5 emulator it also crashes, although you must click right on the clock itself. On iOS4 emulator it works just fine. Without the bar I can click all around the border and nothing bad happens.
So, I can only think that the status bar is dispatching some event or something, which has to be captured and eliminated :)

Being my Obj-C quite short, does anyone have any insights into that matter? I tried to prevent the WebView from scrolling with

> webView.scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881170/status-bar-detects-taps-only-when-the-uiwebview-is-scrolled-down-a-bit) but it didn't do any difference.

Cheers

Comment: actually turns out that it happens after a css3 such as `{-webkit-transform:rotateY(-180deg) scale(0.8)}` which is hardware accelerated.