# Phonegap Xcode iOS app crashes when status bar is tapped

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, cordova

I'm using Xcode 4.3.1 with Phonegap 1.4.1 to build an iPhone app. Whenever I tap the status bar to scroll to top, the app crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I've tried implementing a number of suggestions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539866/phonegap-crashes-when-status-bar-tapped-on-ios5)
.

I've also tried adding variations of the below code:

```
[[[theWebView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setScrollsToTop:NO];

((UIScrollView*)[theWebView.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).scrollsToTop = NO;
```

to the

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*) theWebView 
{
 ...
}
```

within the AppDelegate.m

However, I've have been unable to resolve the issue. My main concern is to stop the app form crashing, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it on iOS Simulator or on real device

Comment: Yeah the error occurs for both simulator and while testing on an actual device

Comment: @CharlieWarner - Did you ever find a solution to this? We are having exactly the same issue.

Comment: @madcapnmckay no, any that I tried either didn't work or were temperamental. We decided to remove the status bar altogether, you can do so by adding `UIStatusBarHidden` set to `YES` within the apps Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

I am using cordova 1.7 and have the same problem. I found a workaround though. You need to patch phonegap by commenting out the creation of invsible iframe which is injected by phonegap to communicate with the native side. In fact, this iframe causes all kinds of rendering issues, not only the status bar problem:

```
if (cordova.commandQueue.length == 1 && !cordova.commandQueueFlushing) {
//        if (!gapBridge) {
//            createGapBridge();
//        }
//        gapBridge.src = "gap://ready";
    location = "gap://ready";
}
```

I didn't find any side effects after I've made the above change. However, I know people complain that some plugins stopped working, e.g. google analytics.